# Best Docker Instance for Pa11y

Tags: docker, accessibility, pa11y

There are a [couple Docker instances that offer Pa11y](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=pa11y&starCount=0), but I'm not sure which is the best one for me. What are the pros or cons with the builds that have been contributed back?

The [Alexiasa](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexiasa/docker-pa11y/) has 2 stars

but hasn't been updated in a year. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

There are (currently) no automated builds from the official upstream repo ([here](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y)), so you should not use any of the images available on Dockerhub. Instead, you should build your own.

Comment: Running docker builds is one thing.  Building docker builds is another. Hopefully the Pa11y team comes up with an official, maintained release at some point.